# How do I generate an image file defined by CSS properties?

Tags: php, css, gdlib

Is there any way to create image file (jpeg or png) from some html DIV which is defined by CSS style properties.

For Example:

[image: div area on HTML page]

```
#canvas_base {
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #1155aa;
}

div.text_div{
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: Tahoma;
 color: #770000;
 line-height: 19px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 76px;
 left: 114px;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
} 
img.image_div{
 position: absolute;
 top: 14px;
 left: 61px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 240px;
 height: 240px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

I'm working on a web application that users use to design their own business card.
After submit they should recieve an jpeg mock-up sample (with designed business card) - something like this:

[image]

Can you give me some short guidance (name of PHP class, technology that should be used etc).

Comment: Remember: content will be at screen resolution, which may not be suitable for print.

Comment: This question fails the "What have you tried?" test. GD or imagemagick would be a good place to start.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: @Diodeus I will TCPDF or DomPDF class to create 300dpi PDF 3.5" x 2" print ready but that is another problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the [GD library of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) which enables you to create images and add texts.

[Here's](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/using-php-gd-library-to-write-text-over-images-using-truetype-fonts/) one article I wrote related with it with a [class I created](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/PHP-Backend/blob/master/textPainter/class.textPainter.php).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). This will allow you to create an HTML document and convert it into an image. You can them composite this image as you see fit using a graphics library.